# JQuery Plugin Pattern Reference / Comparison

Tags: jquery, design-patterns, plugins

I'm looking for a document / website that lays out (at least) the most popular jQuery plugin development patterns and explains when you would each one (advantages, disadvantages, etc.). Does such a reference exist? Is there a list of sites that, when compiled together, would create such a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some further research and found this: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#jquerypluginpatterns